# no bind between jquery and python flask def

Tags: python, jquery, html, flask, http-status-code-404

I am working on a web project using jquery.
I am trying to add a server side layer to the project using flask in python 3.6.

I am getting "error 404" (not found)

I guess my problem starts with the lack of binding between the jquery and the "get JSON".

have already declared the app route, but I am not sure if I did it the right way.

```js
$(function() {
           $('a#process_input').bind('click', function() {
            $.getJSON('/background_process', {
              proglang: $('input[name="proglang"]').val(),
            }, function(data) {
              $("#result").text(data.result);
            });
            return false;
           });
         });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML

 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="div_list_con">
            <h3>Welcome! enter a name?</h3>
                <form>
                    <input type=text size=5 name=proglang>
                    <a href=# id=process_input><button class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button></a>
                </form>
            <p id=result></p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, Response, jsonify
import random, json

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def interactive():

   return render_template('org_structure.html')


@app.route('/background_process')
def background_process():


   try:


      lang = request.args.get('proglang', 0, type=str)

      if lang.lower() == 'python':

         return jsonify(result='You are wise')

      else:

         return jsonify(result='Try again.')

   except Exception as e:

      return str(e)
```

Comment: Just try with <form action="/background_process" method="post"> and assess it in  flask request.form['name'].

Comment: hey, thank you! where should i place "request.form['name']" in the py script?

Comment: Yes, instead of request.args.get use req.form["name"]

Comment: like this: lang = req.form["org_structure.html"]('proglang', 0, type=str) ?

Comment: Lang = request.form["proglang"] or request.form.get("proglang")

Comment: i still get 404 :\

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code and it's working , please go through [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request) for further changes
in flask

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="div_list_con">
            <h3>Welcome! enter a name?</h3>
                <form action="/background_process" method="post">
                    <input type=text size=5 name=proglang>
                    <a href=# id=process_input><button class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button></a>
                </form>
            <p id=result></p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Flask app.py

```
 @app.route('/background_process',methods = ['POST', 'GET']) 
    def background_process(): 
       if request.method == 'POST': 
          user = request.form['proglang']
          print(user)
       return jsonify(username=user)
```

you forget to mention POST or GET method to flask method, so that the reason its throws 404 error

Comment: i still get 404 "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" i have no idea what is wrong. maybe the "@app.route('/background_process'..." is not right?